# Avoid duplicating feedback that are already displayed through a ComponentFeedbackMessageFilter

Tags: wicket, wicket-8

In my form, there is one feedback panel for general feedback messages, and two form input fields, each with its own feedback panel for validation feedback messages. However, when a form input fails to validate, the feedback message appears both in the panel for the field feedback message, and in the panel for general messages. This is not what I want, because the feedback messages are duplicated:

[image: Wicket form validation feedback]

HTML:

```html
<h2>The Form</h2>
<form wicket:id="loginForm">
    <div wicket:id="allFeedback"></div>

    <div wicket:id="usernameFeedback"></div>
    <p>Username: <input wicket:id="username" type="text"/></p>

    <div wicket:id="passwordFeedback"></div>
    <p>Password: <input wicket:id="password" type="password"/><p>

    <input type="submit" name="Login" value="Login"/>
</form>
```

Java:

```java
TextField usernameField = new TextField("username", Model.of(""));
usernameField.setRequired(true);
add(usernameField);

PasswordTextField passwordField = new PasswordTextField("password", Model.of(""));
add(passwordField);

add(new FeedbackPanel("allFeedback"));
add(new FeedbackPanel("usernameFeedback",
                      new ComponentFeedbackMessageFilter(usernameField)));
add(new FeedbackPanel("passwordFeedback",
                      new ComponentFeedbackMessageFilter(passwordField)));
```

Is there a way to prevent the duplication? I do not want the field-specific feedback messages to be duplicated in the general feedback panel.

Comment: See: https://jeremythomerson.com/2011/01/04/catching-all-feedback-messages-that-arent-rendered-by-other-feedback-panels/

Answer (score 0):

check [user guide](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/8.x/single.html#_using_flash_messages) to learn how to implement a custom feedback message filter. This might be useful for the general feedback panel to discard messages from usernameField and passwordField.